Get the Group Name if current logged in user is in an Active Directory Group residing in a SharePoint Group?
I have a requirement to get the current logged in user's group in SharePoint Online. The current logged in user is in an Active Directory Group residing in a SharePoint Group. When I am using the Rest API to query the group it does not return the group where user is added via AD group. Is there a way to get the logged in user's group for this scenario?

You can achieve this using SPFx + PnP JS + Microsoft Graph API.
High-level steps are as below:

It is assumed that you already have a SPFx solution. Install PNP JS and
Microsoft Graph API libraries using command: npm install @pnp/sp @pnp/graph @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client --save
Make sure your app registration in Azure AD has the necessary permissions to read group membership. You might need Group.Read.All and User.Read.All permissions.
React JS component to implement this functionality:


    import * as React from 'react';
    import { sp } from '@pnp/sp/presets/all';
    import { graph } from '@pnp/graph';
    import { MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
    
    class UserGroups extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                spGroups: [],
                userAdGroups: {},
            };
        }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUserSharePointGroups();
    }

    getUserSharePointGroups = async () => {
        try {
            const currentUser = await sp.web.currentUser.get();
            const spGroups = await sp.web.siteGroups();
            const userSpGroups = [];
            const userAdGroups = {};

            for (const group of spGroups) {
                const groupUsers = await sp.web.siteGroups.getById(group.Id).users();
                const isMember = groupUsers.some(user => user.Email === currentUser.Email);
                
                if (isMember) {
                    userSpGroups.push(group);

                    // Fetch AD groups for each user in the SharePoint group
                    for (const user of groupUsers) {
                        const adGroups = await this.getUserAdGroups(user.Email);
                        userAdGroups[user.Email] = adGroups;
                    }
                }
            }

            this.setState({ spGroups: userSpGroups, userAdGroups });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching user groups:", error);
        }
    };

    getUserAdGroups = async (email) => {
        try {
            const client = await this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient();
            const adGroups = await client.api(`/users/${email}/memberOf`).get();
            return adGroups.value.filter(group => group['@odata.type'] === '#microsoft.graph.group').map(group => group.displayName);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching AD groups:", error);
            return [];
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>User SharePoint and AD Groups</h1>
                {this.state.spGroups.map(group => (
                    <div key={group.Id}>
                        <h2>{group.Title}</h2>
                        <ul>
                            {this.state.userAdGroups[group.Email]?.map((adGroup, index) => (
                                <li key={index}>{adGroup}</li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserGroups;

